# What is the best way to connect to a Mysql database in Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

What is the best component to use when connecting to a Mysql  5.1.x in Delphi and why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No other DB components could beat DevArt DB Components, they have [MyDac](http://www.devart.com/mydac/) and [UniDac](http://www.devart.com/unidac/), both of them could use direct access to the database without requiring mysql client to be installed on the client machine, beside they offer fast performance and high quality compared to other components

[Data Access Components for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/mydac/)

[Universal Data Access Components](http://www.devart.com/unidac/)

and check the pages above to know why ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at [AnyDAC](http://www.remobjects.com/anydac.aspx), supports MySQL and a lot of other databases.

Answer (score 2):

[Devart](http://www.devart.com/mydac/) and [microOLAP](http://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/mysqldac/) both offer components to access MySQL databases.  Devart also have [dbExpress drivers](http://www.devart.com/dbx/) for dbExpress users.

Bob Swart has published [Delphi for Win32 VCL Database Development](http://www.lulu.com/content/1165954) on Lulu, if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that MySQL's client dll are GPL-ed, and if you are using it to connect to server, your app must be GPL-ed.

There are alternatives. Components that connect directly to MySQL skipping GPLed dlls. [DevArt](http://www.DevArt.com) has such components (direct and dbx), and there are free components that can connect directily on tory.net.

Comment: Not if you don't distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MySQL, but when I can, I prefer dbExpress.  It's unidirectional, which makes it pretty fast.  Though I haven't done any benchmarking recently.

If dbExpress isn't your thing, I found [this list](http://delphi.about.com/od/mysql/tp/aatpmysql.htm) of components for MySQL access.