# How do I write a database application that can be compiled in both Delphi and Free Pascal?

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, freepascal

I'm writing a simple application which connects to MySQL, selects and updates some rows.

What is the standard or de-facto standard approach to working with databases so that the app compiles both on latest Delphi and FPC?

Comment: This is a "Shopping list" question (please do my research and post a list of things for me to consider), and those types of question are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. There are many links here and on the internet comparing database libraries. Please do your own investigating, and then feel free to come back here with specific questions about differences between a couple of choices. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Comment: @Ken White: I'm asking exactly because there doesn't seem to be a "shopping list" of options. This may indeed degrade into listing your favorite DAC but I'm hoping for a more generic answer, i.e. "work with generic TDataset and use different implementations on different platforms". The task seems pretty common after all.

Comment: @himself you questio nis much more broad than that.  Even DB aside, the very use of LCL/VCL makes it l;ess than warranted to "compile both on latest Delphi and FPC" - even just TThread is slightly different. UniDAC AFAIR supports FPC, AnyDAC did supported. There is ODBC standard... Whatever.

Comment: @Arioch: Alright, I've rephrased the question. Is this better?

Comment: I highly recommend UniDAC(http://www.devart.com/unidac/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/498731/62576, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8369597/62576, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2694412/62576

Comment: Zeos is also pretty decent on both